# array manipulation and counting ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have such an array. Help me to get desirable output.

```
arr = [["IT", "Testing"], ["IT", "Banking Software"], ["IT", "ERP"],
       ["IT", "Testing"], ["IT", "IT Security"], ["IT", "ERP"],
       ["IT", "IT Security"], ["Accounting", "Offshore"], ["IT", "Testing"],
       ["Accounting", "ACCA"]]
```

I want to construct the following array (containing a single hash) from `arr`:

```
[
 {
   "IT" => [["Testing", 3], ["ERP", 2], ["IT Security", 2], ["Banking Software", 1]],
   "Accounting" => [["Offshore", 1], ["ACCA", 1]]
 }
]
```

Tried with .map, .group_by, but still no success. Any help appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "no success"?  Did it not work?  Did it give you invalid output?

Comment: As written, this is a "write code for me" question. I want to help you get past where you're stuck, but unless you share specifics, I can't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code and example**

```
[arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |pair, h| h[pair] += 1 }.
    each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k]=[] }) { |((a,b),n),g| g[a] << [b,n] }]
  #=> [{"IT"=>[["Testing", 3], ["Banking Software", 1], ["ERP", 2], ["IT Security", 2]],
  #    "Accounting"=>[["Offshore", 1], ["ACCA", 1]]}]
```

It's not clear why an array containing a single hash (rather than just the hash) is desired. If the hash is all that's needed, simply remove the outer brackets in the code.

**Explanation**

`Hash.new(0)` is sometimes called a *counting hash*. (See [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-c-new).) If `h = Hash.new(0)` and `h` does not have a key `:cat`, `h[:cat]` returns the default value (here zero), without altering the hash. When Ruby encounters `h[:cat] += 1`, the first thing it does is expand that expression to<sup>1</sup>:

```
h[:cat] = h[:cat] + 1
```

If `h` has a key `:cat`, `h[:cat]` on right side of the equality is the current value for that key, say `8`. We then compute

```
h[:cat] = 8 + 1 #=> 9
```

On the other hand, if `h` does not have a key `:cat`, `h[:cat]` on the right is set to the default value, so we have

```
h[:cat] = 0 + 1 #=> 0
```

Therefore, in the first step we compute a hash as follows:

```
g = arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |pair, h| h[pair] += 1 }
  #=> {["IT", "Testing"]=>3, ["IT", "Banking Software"]=>1, ["IT", "ERP"]=>2,
  #    ["IT", "IT Security"]=>2, ["Accounting", "Offshore"]=>1, ["Accounting", "ACCA"]=>1}
```

This is nearly the same as the simpler form

```
h = {}
arr.each do |pair|
  h[pair] = 0 unless h.key?(pair)
  h[pair] += 1
end
  #=> [["IT", "Testing"], ["IT", "Banking Software"], ["IT", "ERP"],
  #    ["IT", "Testing"], ["IT", "IT Security"], ["IT", "ERP"],
  #    ["IT", "IT Security"], ["Accounting", "Offshore"], ["IT", "Testing"],
  #    ["Accounting", "ACCA"]]
h #=> {["IT", "Testing"]=>3, ["IT", "Banking Software"]=>1, ["IT", "ERP"]=>2,
  #    ["IT", "IT Security"]=>2,
  #    ["Accounting", "Offshore"]=>1, ["Accounting", "ACCA"]=>1}
```

Notice that `each` returns its receiver, so we need the line `h` at the end if this snippet were wrapped in a method.

The second step (using `h` just computed) is a fancy was of implementing the following.

```
g = {}
h.each do |k,n|
  a, b = k 
  g[a] = [] unless g.key?(a)
  g[a] << [b, n]
end
g # => {"IT"=>[["Testing", 3], ["Banking Software", 1], ["ERP", 2], ["IT Security", 2]],
  #     "Accounting"=>[["Offshore", 1], ["ACCA", 1]]}
```

<sup>1 Note that `h[k] =` is *syntactic sugar* for the method [Hash#[]=](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D), whereas `h[k]` on the right of the equality is the method [Hash#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Not quite what you wanted, but I'm sure this will help:

```
arr.group_by(&:first).transform_values { |arr| arr.map { |sub| sub.last }
                                                  .group_by(&:itself)
                                                  .map { |k,v| [k, v.size] } 
                                       }


#=> {  "IT"         => [["Testing", 3],
#                       ["Banking Software", 1],
#                       ["ERP", 2], 
#                       ["IT Security", 2]],
#     
#      "Accounting" => [["Offshore", 1],
#                       ["ACCA", 1]]
#    }
```

You can push it in an array I suppose and Bob's your uncle.

---

Key methods: `transform_values`; `group_by` and `map`. See [www.ruby-doc.org](http://www.ruby-doc.org) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to answer your homework, but here's some pseudo code for you:

```
output = {}

yourarray.each { |item| 
    // Key will be "IT" for the first iteration
    key = item[0];
    // Value will be "Testing" for the first iteration
    value = item[1];
    // Now you want to set Output['IT'] to 1
    // If Output['IT'] was already set, then you need to increment the number
}
```

Comment: This is not my homework!